# Convert date from AS/400 database file

Tags: sql, datetime, time

I'm using MS SQL Server and am Trying to convert the date and time data into something useful for PowerBi and 
can't get the time to work, Date is fine:

```
USE [CDCP_AEP]
GO

select *
from
(SELECT [H1PROD]
        ,convert(DATE,right('0'+str([H1DTTR],len([H1DTTR])),6),102) as 'AssyDate'
        ,[H1TMTR]
        ,right('000000'+str([H1TMTR],len([H1TMTR])),6) 'TempTime'
        ,[H1TYPE]
        ,[H1LOT]
        ,[H1SORD]
        from [AEBPCSUSRF].[JHP1]
        where [H1TYPE] = 'AF' and [H1LOT] <> '')a
    left join
  (select [P1PROD]
         ,[P1LOT]
  from [AEBPCSUSRF].[PLA1])b
    on a.[H1LOT] = b.[P1LOT]
    GO
```

This is the result I get with the above code:

[image: Result]

If I change the date (H1TMTR) line to

```
,convert(TIME,right('000000'+str([H1TMTR],len([H1TMTR])),6)) as 'AssyTime'
```

I get the following error: 
"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert by padding, substring'ing, and putting colons in between the parts like so:

```
DECLARE @H1TMTR VARCHAR(6)='155509'
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,
      SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + @H1TMTR,6),1,2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + @H1TMTR,6),3,2) + ':'
    + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + @H1TMTR,6),5,2)
) AS [Time]
```

Since you are doing this for PowerBI, I presume you will be doing this quite a bit. You should make a scalar function that performs this task on a column so it only needs written once.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yeah that looks like a logical solution. It keeps giving me the following error though:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Comment: @HindsKA The SQL above give you an error when you run it exactly as it is typed?

Comment: yes. There seems to be a problem with "declare", no idea why

Comment: @HindsKA what application are you using to execute that SQL?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server